# Swift Azure Mobile QuickStart - Add and sync PNG image

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

New to iPhone, Swift.   Using XCode 9.3

I am trying to modify the Azure QuickStart iPhone Swift app to include an Images.xcassets PGN image.

The app uses:  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library.md

I only want to work with 1 Azure Sql Server table and NOT use Azure BLOB storage.

Method:  Convert the PNG to Base64 String

Swift code changes
1. QSTodoDataModel.xcdatamodeid - Added Attribute: pic, Type: String
2. Convert the PNG to type Base64 String

```
let myPicUI = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "apic")
 // ** Also tried: let myPicUI : UIImage = UIImage(named: "apic")!

 let myPicNSData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myPicUI)! as NSData
 let myPicstrBase64 = myPicNSData.base64EncodedString(options: 
NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
```

// Create NSDictionary INSERT record -

```
let itemToInsert = ["pic" : myPicstrBase64,  "text": text, "complete": 
false, "__createdAt": Date()] as [String : Any]


 UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    self.table!.insert(itemToInsert) {
        (item, error) in
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: " + (error! as NSError).description)
        }
```

App Save & Sync Failed:  The User entered "text" field value is added and displays in the table view.  When attempt to SYNC to AZURE via pull down table screen, the record disappears from the table view.   Querying Sql Server ToDoItem table directly, no record inserted.

Test: Mobile Sync Successful when directly using String: "TestString"

```
let itemToInsert = ["pic" : "TestString",  "text": text, "complete": false, "__createdAt": Date()] as [String : Any]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: In Visual Studio, added " pic string" and then published to Azure.

namespace capp01Service.DataObjects
{
    public class TodoItem : EntityData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }

        public string pic { get; set; }    // ADDED 
    }
}

Comment: More info: Running the Quickstart iPhone app on the Visual Studio published  Azure site, Entity Framework creates the Sql Server TodoItems table with field "string pic" defined as database type nvarchar(max, null)   ( 2gb max size ).

Comment: More Info:   PNG converted to myPicstrBase64 string length less than 4,000,000

Comment: In code, myPicstrBase64 was defined to 4 MB character string,   The Sync worked !!!  base64EncodedString is not creating a "Sync-able" String.

Comment: let myPicstrBase64 = myPicNSData.base64EncodedString()   - Sync Failed.

Answer (score 0):

Success !!

Convert to String:  let myPicstrBase64 = myPicNSData.base64EncodedString()

I am using the Free Azure Sql Server DB.   The XCode error output window displayed database no space message.

Purge table: Toitems

Hope this helps anyone learning Swift and Azure Mobile Service.